# How to return a valid iterator in C++?

Tags: c++, function, iterator

I'm writing a function to find element in the vector and return an iterator to that element:

```
vector<int>::iterator findelement(vector<int> &ivec, int target)
{
    auto it=ivec.begin();
    while(it!=ivec.end())
    {
        if(*it=target)
            return it;
        else ++it;
    }
    return ivec.end();
}
```

Then I copy the return iterator to another iterator. I can dereference the iterator correctly:

```
vector<int> numbers{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
auto iter=findelement(numbers,5);
cout<<*iter;
```

The output is 5.
But,when I increment/decrement the iterator, there are somethings wrong:

```
--iter;
cout<<*iter; //I think the output should be 4, but the output is 134281917!
```

Is the return value of the findelement function wrong?

Comment: `*it=target`... You mean, `*it==target`?

Comment: Just use `std::find`...please.

Comment: Is ``numbers`` still in scope when you try and use `++` or `--`? And/or have you modified it?

Comment: T.C.:Yes...I make a stupid mistake.Thank you!

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. *warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(*it=target)
    return it;
```

This assigns `target` to `*it`. Since `target` is `5`, the value of the expression is `5` as well, which is equivalent to `true`. Thus, with a nonzero `target`, your function will assign `target` to the first element of `ivec` and return `ivec.begin()`. It should be obvious that decrementing that iterator results in undefined behavior.

Note that both g++ and clang [emits a warning on this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30aefd4a3e70df31) with `-Wall` (clang emits a warning even without it). You should always compile your code at high warning settings.

Comment: You might want to use the iterator in a non-const way. For example, changing the element after `5` (if it exists) to `6`. The beauty of `std::find` is that it returns what you give it, so if you need a modifiable result, give it modifiable iterators.

Comment: @chris Good point. I've taken that out.

Answer (score 3):

The first element of `numbers` is being overwritten by your search value.  When the assignment happens, the assignment expression is true and returns the iterator to the first element.

```
if(*it=target) {
   return it;
}
```

Because you are already at the beginning, the iterator is not decrementable (or depending on your compiler settings, will print out the value of the location just before your vector).  To fix this, do a comparison instead of assignment (`*it == target`).